# Debugging Django/Gunicorn behind Nginx

Tags: django, debugging, nginx, gunicorn

Fresh install of Nginx, Gunicorn, Supervisor, New Relic, Django, Postgres, etc. Hitting the URL gives a big fat "Internal Server Error."

Turning debug on in the Nginx configuration gives a whole lot of detail, but nothing that points to what is causing the 500 error (just that it is happening.)

Next, I shut down Gunicorn via supervisorctl and started the application up via `python manage.py runserver`, hit the URL, and everything is running fine.

Step back, shut off `runserver` and started Gunicorn manually using `bin/gunicorn_django` and this is the closest to a usable trace log that I've been able to get to:

```
2012-09-05 21:39:25 [5927] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somewhere/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 102, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/somewhere/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/somewhere/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in get_response
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
  File "/somewhere/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

I'm not asking for an answer to what is going on here, because I know this is not enough detail to figure out  much. The `ROOT_URLCONF` issue is generic and could be caused by a lot of things. My question is what are some next steps I can use to continue tracking down what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: The issue happened to be gunicorn actually not being able to find the settings file. After specifying the directory where the settings reside in my supervisor config, it started working. Happy that I got it figured out, still confused as to why it is necessary. The same app runs on 2 other servers fine without the need for this specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mention of `Settings` not `settings` (notice the capital) is suspicious. I've noticed personally from using Aptana Studio, that one of the autocomplete choices that appears after typing `from django.conf import` is `Settings`, but that's obviously not what you really want. Perhaps something similar happened and you accepted the incorrect autocomplete choice? I'd search your project for `Settings` (with case-sensitivity on, of course), and change it to lowercase as appropriate.